# Set text first five seconds then start counting

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer

I want to set a text the first five seconds then after that should the timer on the screen show. So the timer is counting the first five but not showing until five seconds later. Here are some of my code. I have more but just pasted the countdowntimer onTick-part. The timeChosen variable comes from what the user has chosen from 1-5(minutes).

```
new CountDownTimer(timeChosen * 60000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));



                   if(millis+12000>=(timeChosen * 60000)){
                    System.out.println("test");
                    textTimer.setText("Do Exercise");
                }
                else
                {
                    textTimer.setText(hms);
                }

                }
```

Comment: Why is it not working? it should show "Do Exercise" once millis are over timeChosen your explanation suggest you want <= not >=

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your milliseconds left to a integer, so it will be more precise when you want to compare it.
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)

Just try something like this:

```
 long delayTime = 5000; //5s of delay in millisenconds
    int timeChosen = 3; //3 mins
    new CountDownTimer((timeChosen * 60000) + delayTime, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (delayTime == 0) {
                //Start your progressBar or do whatever you want
            }
            else
            {
                textTimer.setText(delayTime);
                delayTime--;
            }


        }
    }
```